# Can you assign 'self' with new arguments not from the constructor?

Tags: python

Given this class:

```
class PythonClass():

    def  __init__(self,arg1='1',arg2='2')
        self.arg3 = '3'
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg4 = arg3 + '1'
```

Can you assign `self.arg3` and `self.arg4` or will it give a Syntax error?

[Taken from here](http://blog.packetheader.net/2014/01/sending-80211-packets-with-scapy.html)

```
class Scapy80211():

    def  __init__(self,intf='wlan0',ssid='test',\
        source='00:00:de:ad:be:ef',\
        bssid='00:11:22:33:44:55',srcip='10.10.10.10'):
        self.rates = "\x03\x12\x96\x18\x24\x30\x48\x60"
        self.ssid    = ssid
        self.source  = source
        self.srcip   = srcip
        self.bssid   = bssid
        self.intf    = intf
        self.intfmon = intf + 'mon'
```

Comment: You should try that yourself in the interpreter before asking and all will be clear.

Comment: Why should that be a syntax error? Your example will get a `NameError` because `arg3` isn't defined (you can replace it with `self.arg3`).

Comment: I tried the program. It works but for self.rates - rates doesnt come from anywhere

Comment: Folks, has no one here programmed in enough different languages to recognize that it's *not at all obvious* to someone coming from any C-type language that you could have a language that allows the existence of undeclared object properties?

Comment: @LarryLustig I was taught programming with Java in both my HS and University (so far). Of-course to me this doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes, I consider the negative votes on this question an embarrassment to StackOverflow.  Your question is fine; I hope you find my answer (below) comprehensible and useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run that code, you'll find that it executes without a syntax error, which answers your basic question.

You probably want to know *why* Python lets you make assignments to random properties of the class without declaring the existence of those properties in any way -- as required by other languages you may be familiar with.

It is because in Python an object's collection of attributes is essentially a string-indexed dictionary of values.  Attribute assignment is just a dictionary operation.  If the dictionary already has the specified key (attribute name) the value is replaced with the newly assigned one.  If the dictionary *does not* have that key (that is, the object has no attribute with the given name) the key and value are *added* to the dictionary.

To answer your next question -- yes, different instances of an object can therefore have different attributes than other objects of the same class.

And to answer your next, next question -- yes, coming from a language which requires declared, typed attributes this is a very different programming paradigm.